# Hide the link of current page.

Tags: php, pagination

The code which I use to show Links of `10 pages` per page in pagination is:

```
$start = ( floor($page/10) * 10 ) + 1;
for( $i = $start; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
if( $i >= ($start + 10)){
    break;
}
else{

}
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i  .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

I want to hide the current page link such that if I was on Page 7 it will hide the link 7. can anybody help?

Comment: do you know on which page are you currently in?

Comment: yes my page is showing links from 1 to 10. the thing I want is to hide that link which I select.

Comment: *FYI* Using un-escaped `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will open you up to XSS and CSRF attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo only if the page is not equal to the current page.

```
if ($page != $i) echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i  .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

Comment: than you so much my friend. your answer is accurately right too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the current page and then just use a simple condition. Something like:

```
$currentPage = $_GET["page"];
$start = ( floor($page/10) * 10 ) + 1;
for( $i = $start; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
  if( $i >= ($start + 10)){
    break;
  }
  else {
    if ($i!=$currentPage) echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i     .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  }
}
```

Also, I moved `echo` inside the `else {}` part because I believe it should be there.

Comment: than you so much my friend. your answer is accurately right `:) `